# Partial fraction decomposition: $f(x) = \frac{x}{1-x-x^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the function $$f(x) = \frac{x}{1-x-x^2}$$
(a) Determine a recursive formula for the coefficients $c_n$ of the Maclaurin series of $f$.

(b)Using the partial fractions decomposition of  $ f(x)$, determine the Maclaurin series of f in a second way, thereby finding an explicit formula for the coefficients $c_n$.

For the (a) part, I get the recursive formula: $$c_0 = 0, c_1 = 1, c_n = c_{n-1}+c_{n-2}, $$ which is Fibonacci numbers.

But for the second part, I don't know how to decompose the fraction. If I do know it, I think I can solve the entire problem.

Please help me to deal with this problem. Thanks.

Comment: See http://austinrochford.com/posts/2013-11-01-generating-functions-and-fibonacci-numbers.html

Comment: Are you familiar with the Method of Partial Fractions; particularly the case of linear over quadratic? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac{x}{1-x-x^2} = -\dfrac{x}{(x-a)(x-b)} = -\dfrac{1}{a-b}\left(\dfrac{x}{x-a}-\dfrac{x}{x-b}\right)= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\dfrac{\dfrac{x}{b}}{1-\dfrac{x}{b}}-\dfrac{\dfrac{x}{a}}{1-\dfrac{x}{a}}\right)= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\dfrac{x}{b}\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\dfrac{x}{b}\right)^n- \dfrac{x}{a}\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\dfrac{x}{a}\right)^n\right)$, with $a = \dfrac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}, b= \dfrac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Expand the above series and collect coefficients you will get the fibonacci general term as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : $$\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}=\frac{A}{r-x}+\frac{B}{x+r+1}$$

where $r=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

You can use partial fractions, but they are somewhat unwieldy because you introduce irrational roots.

Instead of using partial fractions, complete the square in the quadratic denominator.  Thus $1-x-x^2 = (5/4)-u^2$ with $u = x+(1/2)$.

Now the integral should be easy to find as an inverse hyperbolic tangent function.  If you want logarithms, use

$tanh^{-1}(a) = (1/2) log ((1+a)/(1-a))$